# Why can I access static class method in App_Code for an ASP.NET project NOT for an MVC2 Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the same asp.net **MVC2 project** (no problem when it is a pure ASP.NET project), I have created 2 classes in App_Code without no namespace, one is normal class, the other is static.

I can access public methods of instance class from anywhere, I cannot access public methods of the static class. Why ? And how can I access them then ?

```
    public class MyWebservice
    {

        public stMyWebservice()
        {                                       

        }

        public String getText() {
        }
    }


    public static class Helper
    {

        public static String getText()
        {




        }
    }
```

I access the static class inside the index.aspx like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Helper.getText();                  
    }
</script>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you post your classes declaration?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access the static class? Please show an example of your code

Comment: @user310291, can you post *exact* classes declaration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your static class should be accessible as the other class. My guess you declared your static class without `public` access modifier, e.g.:

```
static class MyClass
{
}
```

If you declared the class in such a way, it will have `internal` access modifier. This means, it will be accessible within assembly. App_Code folder compiles into a single assembly and if you try to use you class outside the App_Code folder, you will get an error.

**EDIT:** one more - there is no difference whether the class declared as `static` or not in this case. If the classes have the same access modifiers each class will be accessible in a place where the second is.

So, as you provided not exact classes declaration, my second guess is: you have declared your static class inside a non-static one e.g.:

```
public class MyWebservice
{
    public static class Helper
    {
        public static String getText()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the static class is also accessible through the parent class name:

```
var text = MyWebservice.Helper.getText()
```

And finally, I created a simple website that demonstrates this and posted it to [google docs](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2z9c2WRBmDbY2NiYmU4ZjUtNWE1YS00Yzk5LTkyZjQtOGE2NDcwOGUzNmQ2&hl=en).

**EDIT II:** your last edit shows that you have actually a **web application**, not a web site. For web applications `App_Code` folder is not necessary.  In a web site, class files are compiled dynamically at run-time and must live in the `App_Code` folder. In a web application, everything is compiled statically and class files can live anywhere in your web application.

In that case I see the reason of this behavior in incorrect `Build Action` of the code files in your folder. I'm guessing it set to `Content` but should be set to `Compile` instead (you can do it by pressing `F4` on your code file).

Comment: ok I found it works in asp.net project like yours I downloaded thanks, and it doesn't on mine which is an asp.net mvc2 project weird isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry I'm novice at asp.net and of course also mvc I don't understand what you mean by Build Action. What F4 differs from F6 ? And if in a web application I can put code anywhere can I let it in App_Code ?

Comment: For info I created the asp.net sample with the usual template from visual studio and just added the equivalent of your sample nothing more.

Comment: @user310291, yes you could put it everywhere but I suggest you to put it in a different assembly and then add a reference to it to your web application. `Build Action` is a property of you code file; just point to the code file, right click, then `Properties` and then you see this property (F4 is a shortcut for this).

Answer (score 8):

Be sure that the **Build Action** for the class is set to **Compile**.

Go to your **App_Code** folder, and select your class.  Look in the properties page.  Find **Build Action**. Set it to **Compile**.  Then you should have access to the methods and properties of that object elsewhere in your application.

Comment: Thank you! This was the issue!